# How do I get Notepad++ to put a consistent single space between words on the same line

Tags: notepad++

I have 10 txt files with 1000 lines each, and they're all horribly formatted, with uneven space between "columns'. I neeed to put a single space between words (names in this case) so Access can turn each row into a proper column . How can I get Notepad to put a consistent one space between these words instead of the varying spacing as seen here:

[image: https://puu.sh/zUSXq/fe11893126.png]

Comment: I mean it's probably not optimal but if you opened all 10 in tabs in notepad++ and do a search and replace (control + H), there is an option for replace on all files open.  Then simply do about 5-7 search replaces for four space "    " to one space " " then 5 spaces "     " to one space " ", etc....

Comment: or check the regex box and replace ( +) for ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex expression to do this.

- Select the 'Regular Expression' search mode
- Enter `[ ]+` in the 'Find what' box
- Enter  (a single space) in the 'Replace with' box.

This looks for one or more spaces, and replaces with a single space.

[image]

Comment: For some reason this did not work, and I made sure all settings in the window matched. It said it found 4,000 occurances but the uneven spacing is still there when I clicked Replace All.

Comment: It might be that you have tabs as well as spaces in the file. Instead of searching for spaces, try searching for tabs `\t+` and replace them with a single space. It would be worthwhile turning on the 'show whitespace and TAB' option under the View menu. Tabs will look like arrows and spaces as dots.

Comment: I used the Show command and there was a combo of spaces and tabs, using the \t did not work either, tried with and without [ ] around it.

Comment: Ah, I put a space after the \t in brackets and this fixed it! Thank you so much!